# Continuous map on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $f$ be a continuous map on $\mathbb{R}^d$. We denote $A=\min\limits_{x\in K}f(x).$

I want to prove that there exist $\epsilon_1>0$ such that

$$f(x)\le \epsilon_1\Rightarrow f(x)\ge \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$$

Please help me to do so. Thanks

Comment: This is not true. But if you change $f(x)\geq \epsilon_0$ into $f(x)\geq \frac{\epsilon_0}{2}$ it will be true.

Comment: yes that is what i need to prove, can you please help me to prove it. I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is continuous and $\frac{\epsilon_0}2>0$, we know that for each $p \in K$ the set $f^{-1}\left(\{y\in \mathbb{R}:|y-f(p)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2\}\right)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^d$. We also know that $\underset{p \in K}\bigcup f^{-1}\left(\{y\in \mathbb{R}:|y-f(p)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2\}\right)$ contains $K$. Since the collection of open sets $\big\{ f^{-1}\left(\{y\in \mathbb{R}:|y-f(p)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2\}\right) \big\}_{p \in K}$ covers $K$, there exists $\epsilon_1>0$ so that for every $p \in K$ we have $B_d(\,p, \epsilon_1) \subseteq f^{-1}\left(\{y\in \mathbb{R}:|y-f(q)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2\}\right)$ for some $q \in K$ (Lebesgue's Number Lemma). Thus if $d(x,K)<\epsilon_1$, then $|f(x)-f(q)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2$ for some $q \in K$. And since $f(q)\geq \epsilon_0$, we therefore have $f(x)>f(q)-\frac{\epsilon_0}2\geq \frac{\epsilon_0}2$.

Invoking Lebesgue's Number Lemma allows us to get at the fact that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $K$.

Comment: @ Matt A Pelto, i didn't understand why "for every $p \in K$ we have $B_d(\,p, \epsilon_1) \subseteq f^{-1}\left(\{y\in \mathbb{R}:|y-f(q)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2\}\right)$ for some $q \in K$ (Lebesgue's Number Lemma)" implies  "if $d(x,K)<\epsilon_1$, then $|f(x)-f(q)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2$ for some $q \in K$." Can you please explain this more on details? thanks in advance

Comment: $d(x,K)<\epsilon_1$ implies $x \in B_d(p, \epsilon_1)$ for some $p \in K$, and $B_d(p, \epsilon_1) \subseteq f^{-1}\left(\{y\in \mathbb{R}:|y-f(q)|<\frac{\epsilon_0}2\}\right)$ for some $q \in K$.

Comment: that is clear now for me. I have an other question, if w consider additionaly a continuous map $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $g(x)=0$ if and only if $x$ belongs to $K.$ How can us prove that there is  $\epsilon_2>0$ such that \begin{align*}
d(x,K)\ge \epsilon_1\Rightarrow |g(x)|\ge \epsilon_2\;.
\end{align*}Thanks in advance

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the way your followup question has been worded. Where does $\epsilon_1$ come from?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the following three facts (prove them!):

1. For points outside of $K$, we have $d(x,K) = d(x,\partial K)$.
2. The boundary $\partial K$ is again compact.
3. $f$ is continuous, use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ formulation of continuity.

Comment: Can I answer as follows: suppose that for all $\epsilon_1>0$ there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $d(x,K)\le \epsilon_1$ and $f(x)<\frac{\epsilon_0}{2}.$ Then we could let $\epsilon_1$ tends to zero and this would imply that $d(x,K)=0$ which in turn implies that $x\in K$ since $K$ is compact. Thus $f(x)\ge \epsilon_0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Aymen This looks like a good argument. The one I had in mind was that for each of the points $x\in\partial K$ there exists $r_x>0$ so that $f\ge\tfrac{\epsilon_0}{2}$ on $B(x,r_x)$. Since $\partial K$ is compact, it is covered by a finite number of these balls $B(x_i,r_{x_i})$. Then you want to prove that there exists $\epsilon_1$ such that for all $x\in\partial K$, the ball $B(x,\epsilon_1)$ is contained in $\bigcup_iB(x_i,r_{x_i})$, and conclude.

Comment: i think that what i said is false. In fact when letting $\epsilon_1$ tends to zero $d(x,K)$ do not tend to $d(x,K)$ since $x$ depends on $\epsilon_1$